# Session StateServer deserialization exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to get or remove objects from session that could not be deserialized?
(objects are stored in session by another library which was loaded at runtime using `Assembly.LoadFrom` method)

i have to write method which executes on every request
but i think it is bad idea that it iterates through whole session
is there better way to delete not deserializable objects from session?

```
public void ResetSessionIfNeeded()
{
    if (Session.Mode == SessionStateMode.SQLServer || 
        Session.Mode == SessionStateMode.StateServer)
    {
        var index = 0;
        var count = Session.Count;
        while (index < count)
        {
            try
            {
                var tempObj = Session[index];
                index++;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Session.RemoveAt(index);
                count--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem is, this works, but he says he doesn't want to run over 500 objects each 500 mb before he finds non-deserializable object, he asks if there is any other method to determine undeserialize objects without loading them, (maybe even before putting them into session or after )